# Hyperlinks in bibtex bibliography

Tags: bibtex

I am using `BibTex` to write the bibliography of my document. I also want that when I cite some of my references an hyperlink appears in the pdf so as when one click it it will redirect to the bibliography item that corresponds.

The problem is that with my actual setting next to the bibliography entries a series of numbers appers which redirect to every page where I have a reference of that particular entry. For example:

`[9] John C. Strikwerda. Finite Difference Schemes and Partial Differential Equations. Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, Philadelphia, 2004. 16, 19, 20`

Notice the numbers 16,19, 20 at the end. Those are in fact references to the pages where I referenced that particular book. I would like them to disappear. The references in the pages appear as `[9]` where the number 9 is a reference to the bibliography entry. This is my desired setup.

A sample to reproduce my issue:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,       
    linkcolor=blue,          
    citecolor=green,       
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue          
}

\begin{document}
 %citation
 An interesting book \cite{vnewmann}

 % biblio
 \bibliographystyle{plain}
 \bibliography{trashbib}

\end{document}
```

With the `trashbib.bib` file as follows

```
@article{vnewmann,
   author={{V}on{N}ewmann, {J}. and {R}ichtmyer, {R}. {D}.},
   title={{A} {M}ethod for the {N}umerical {C}alculation of {H}ydrodynamic {S}hocks},
   journal={{J}ournal of {A}pplied {P}hysics},
   volume={21},
   year = 1950,
   pages = {232-237}
 }
```

Anyone knows how to get rid of the numbers (with references to the text) next to the bibliography items while keeping the references to the bibbliography in the text?

Comment: Aside: It's better to write `{Calculation}` rather than `{C}alculation`. You'll still get the right capitalisation, but there's no danger of messing up the kerning between the `C` and the `a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those numbers are called 'back references'. Remove the `[pagebackref=true]` bit, and they'll go away.